# api request parameters are ignored

Tags: regex, beautifulsoup, wikipedia-api

This code works as expected and shows 3 recent wikipedia editors.

My question is that if I uncomment the second URL line, I should get **Urmi27** *three times or None* if the user is not listed.
But I get the same list for both URL. Is "action" ignored by api request?

```
import requests

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

#URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=feedcontributions&user=Urmi27"

PARAMS = {
    "format": "json",
    "rcprop": "comment|loginfo|title|ids|sizes|flags|user",
    "list": "recentchanges",
    "action": "query",
    "rclimit": "3"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
DATA = R.json()

RECENTCHANGES = DATA['query']['recentchanges']

for rc in RECENTCHANGES:
    print (rc['user'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining GET parameter in 2 places (in the URL and in the `PARAMS` dictionary) and the API is prioritizing the `PARAMS`

The `query` and `feedcontributions` actions are very different, using different parameters and different return formats.

To use the `feedcontributions` action, you would need something like this:

```html
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"


PARAMS = {
"action":"feedcontributions",
"user":"Urmi27"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
xml_tree = ET.fromstring(R.content)


for child in xml_tree:
print(child.tag, child.attrib)
for channel in child:
    for elements in channel:
        if elements.tag == "description":
            print(elements.text)
```

[API REF](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=feedcontributions&tableofcontents=0)

Comment: Thanks. How do I extract the first line in <p> of the description tag? For e.g. only "Urmi27: Grammar and sentence formation." should be returned.

Comment: @shantanuo I updated the above answer with a crude XML parser to get the description tag